# How to store large data source while using jQuery aotocomplete in the front end?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have 1000k rows of data, it looks like zipcode/city/state, if you type 95101 in the website text field, it will show san jose, ca; and complete the text field autocomplete.

What kind of data structure are you choosing to store the whole zipcode/city/state in united states?

Maybe 1000k rows. If I load the data source to local, it seems like wasting time. If I write the data source in the array of JavaScript, the array is too large, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean 1 million rows?

Use a remote datasource to do the search on the server on only return a small number of rows.

eg [jQuery autocomplete remote example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery ui autocomplete with a remote datasource - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Excerpt from there:

> The datasource is a server-side script which returns JSON data, specified via a simple URL
>   for the source-option. In addition, the minLength-option is set to 2
>   to avoid queries that would return too many results and the
>   select-event is used to display some feedback.

Code sample from there:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If I use JSON, I have to download 1000k rows each time?

Comment: No. The web service you call would take in a parameter (may be the first two digits of the zip code and filter the results down to only those matching it). WHy don't you take a look at the link in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Such a huge amount of data, I recommend you using remote call instead of storing in local array or object. But I believe storing in object is a good option as compared to an array as it creates hash.